# find a regular expression for strings containing the substring aba over the alphabet {a, b}? (formal language theory)

Tags: regex, regular-language, formal-languages

The questions asks to find a regular expression for strings containing the substring aba over the alphabet {a, b}.

Does this mean anything can precede/procede aba so that the regular expression would be:

```
(aUb)*(aba)*(aUb)*
```

or is the question simply looking for:

```
(aba)*
```

Note: U means union and * means 0 or more times.

Answer (score 4):

Since * means 0 or more, ε is in the first language, while you do not want it (it doesn't contain aba). You are looking for `(aUb)*aba(aUb)*`.

Answer (score 0):

A substring is defined as

> noun
>
> a string that is part of a longer string

Also note that the second expression is a subset of the first.

Answer (score 0):

The former: any string that contains `aba` at least once.